# Defining relationship on pivot table elements in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, eloquent

I'm building a small application on `laravel 5.4` where I'm having following models and relationship:

**Interaction Model:**

```
public function contactsAssociation()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'contact_interaction',  'interaction_id', 'contact_id')->withPivot('company_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Contact Model:**

```
public function company()
{
    return $this
        ->belongsToMany('App\Company', 'company_contact','contact_id', 'company_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

and **Company Model:**

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'company_contact', 'company_id','contact_id');
}
```

Now I'm fetching some data something like this:

```
$tempData['contacts'] = $interaction->contactsAssociation()->with('company')->get();
```

I want to extract company data from the pivot table which is mentioned in the relationship. Currently I can't find solution so I have to do:

```
$tempData['contacts'] = $interaction->contactsAssociation()->get();
$companies = [];
foreach($tempData['contacts'] as $contact)
{
    $companies[] = Company::find($contact->pivot->company_id);
}
$tempData['company'] = $companies;
```

Guide me on this, thanks,

Comment: Im not sure of the question - does the above code work or not?

Comment: Yes this works as expected.

Comment: You can create `Pivot` Class and define relationship on that
See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47673390/3563059

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array to the `withPivot()` function with every field you want to retrieve:

```
public function contactsAssociation()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Contact', 'contact_interaction',  'interaction_id', 'contact_id')
        ->withPivot(['company_id', 'other_field'])
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I know I can add pivot fields, I want to add eloquent relation through pivot table.